# Вывод элементов списков

Tags: python, list, список

Есть список с значения

```
list = [('0', '0_list.PNG', 1),
                ('1', '2_list.PNG', 2),
                ('2', '4_list.PNG', 0),
                ('3', '6_list.PNG', 0),
                ('4', '8_list.PNG', 0),
                ('5', '10_list.PNG', 0),
                ('6', '12_list.PNG', 3),
                ('8', '16_list.PNG', 0),
                ('9', '18_list.PNG', 0),
                ('10', '20_list.PNG', 0),
                ('11', '22_list.PNG', 4),
                ('13', '26_list.PNG', 0),
                ('14', '28_list.PNG', 0)]
```

подскажите как вывести его в таком формате

первый принт

```
('0', '0_list.PNG', 1)
```

второй принт

```
('1', '2_list.PNG', 2),
('2', '4_list.PNG', 0),
('3', '6_list.PNG', 0),
('4', '8_list.PNG', 0),
('5', '10_list.PNG', 0),
```

третий принт

```
('6', '12_list.PNG', 3),
('8', '16_list.PNG', 0),
('9', '18_list.PNG', 0),
('10', '20_list.PNG', 0),
```

четвертый принт

```
('11', '22_list.PNG', 4),
('13', '26_list.PNG', 0),
('14', '28_list.PNG', 0)
```

Comment: при чем здесь фильтрация? каков алгоритм такого именно вывода?

Comment: @strawdog, не именно такого, я имел в виду как написать алгоритм который будет выводить элементы списка с такой логикой

Comment: Не видно попыток решения данной задачи самостоятельно.

Comment: @СергейКох данную задачу, я решаю с 3 часов дня но дальше outofrange при удаление элементов из списка не продвинулся

Comment: @СергейКох в данный момент попытки показать не могу, был вывод с двумя, а т.е выводялся первый прин и далее часть второго после чего скрипт выпадал в ошибку outofrange

Comment: @СергейКох посчитал длину списка, далее через if начал сравнивать не равен ли элемент списка нулю  после чего добавил элемент в отдельный список из исходного его удалив после чего ещё раз прошёлся по списку что бы посмотреть равен или нет следующий нулю после того как удостоверился что элемент не равен нулю вывел из второго списка все данный и очистил его

Comment: первый принт выводит просто list[0]

Comment: @СергейКох Дело в том что это динамически генерируемый список, далее с вывод этого списка будут тоже происходить операции. в аналогичном списке будет до +- 200 значений

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно разбить ваш список таким способом:

```
from itertools import groupby

res = []
for k,g in groupby(list_,lambda x: x[2]):
    if k: res.append(list(g))
    else: res[-1].extend(list(g))
```

теперь в res у вас список списков, можете делать с ним что хотите

```
[[('0', '0_list.PNG', 1)],
 [('1', '2_list.PNG', 2),
  ('2', '4_list.PNG', 0),
  ('3', '6_list.PNG', 0),
  ('4', '8_list.PNG', 0),
  ('5', '10_list.PNG', 0)],
 [('6', '12_list.PNG', 3),
  ('8', '16_list.PNG', 0),
  ('9', '18_list.PNG', 0),
  ('10', '20_list.PNG', 0)],
 [('11', '22_list.PNG', 4),
  ('13', '26_list.PNG', 0),
  ('14', '28_list.PNG', 0)]]
```

Comment: Интересное решение, не сразу дошло как тут группы можно использовать

Comment: @SergFSM очень интересное решение, спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Я бы ввел бы два списка: результирующий и временный. Во временный собирал бы по указанной в Вашем примере логике, где первый набор имеет ненулевой третий элемент, а дальше добавлял бы в список все наборы с нулевым третьим элементом. Как только снова встречаем ненулевой элемент в наборе, то временный список добавляем в результирующий и обновляем временный список новым набором.

```
list_ = [('0', '0_list.PNG', 1),
        ('1', '2_list.PNG', 2),
        ('2', '4_list.PNG', 0),
        ('3', '6_list.PNG', 0),
        ('4', '8_list.PNG', 0),
        ('5', '10_list.PNG', 0),
        ('6', '12_list.PNG', 3),
        ('8', '16_list.PNG', 0),
        ('9', '18_list.PNG', 0),
        ('10', '20_list.PNG', 0),
        ('11', '22_list.PNG', 4),
        ('13', '26_list.PNG', 0),
        ('14', '28_list.PNG', 0)]

res = []
tmp = []
for row in list_:
    if not tmp:
        tmp = [row, ]
    else:
        if row[2]:
            res.append(tmp)
            tmp = [row, ]
        else:
            tmp.append(row)    
res.append(tmp)

for r in res:
    print('\n')
    print(*r, sep='\n')
```